# Closing child silverlight window before it is completely loaded crashes Parent window

Tags: javascript, vb.net, silverlight, internet-explorer, ckeditor

Since i know you all like context, this problem has stemmed from the inability to find a Rich Text Editor for Silverlight that can handle complex HTML formatting correctly.

The solution that was decided upon includes opening a new IE window, and running an instance of Silverlight along with CKEditor, an open source HTML based RTE.

We have ironed out almost every issue involving communication, loading, timing etc. However one issue remains:

If you close the child window before it has finished loading the Silverlight object, it will cause the parent window to reload. Specifically it seems that the parent window closes and re-opens. No errors are thrown. I have seen issues similar to this when the plug-in crashes. However that seems to reload any and all Silverlight instances. This specific issue only reloads the parent, other windows are unaffected.

If you have any ideas as to why this might be happening, please comment or respond. I will post code as needed. Also, if you have any work-around ideas, those would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

Greg

Comment: Having spent a year fighting this problem, I feel your pain.  And I say: abandon hope all ye who enter here.  But your hack may work.  When you say "the Silverlight object", which object do you mean?  How are you loading the external IE window, and what does the plumbing between Silverlight and IE look like?

Comment: From the parent i am invoking a javascript function that just calls window.open(). That window then calls the Silverlight.createObject() method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). When the silverlight loads, it sends a ready command to the javascript, which serves as the interface for communication between the windows.

Comment: Why do you need to create a Silverlight object, instead of just invoking the IE page directly?  When I ran into this situation, I implemented it like so: make a placeholder control that shows a plain text version of the HTML.  When you click this, it uses window.open to open the web page with the proper HTML editor, in your case, CKEditor.  In *that* page, you can WYSIWYG edit it, save the HTML to the database or whatever you want to do with it, and then use some javascript to post the HTML back to the the calling Silverlight page, where you convert to plaintext and display in the placeholder.

Comment: Let me first thank you for your replies. Unfortunately we need to incorporate functionality from our native silverlight application as options in the RTE. Essentially we are overlaying a toolbar on top of part of the CKEditor toolbar with silverlight buttons, styled to look the same. These buttons allow us to access email templates, marketing links etc from our system in a method that keeps to the same UX experience and reuses our architecture. The silverlight toolbar then communicates via js back and forth to the CKEditor itself.

Comment: I went down a similar road, but I was never able to made the transition seamless, and got worn down by one problem after another, some of them pretty serious.  Eventually, we decided to port the thing to MVC, because it was too painful.  Would it be that hard to recreate just the HTML editing GUI in the HTML app?  Regarding your immediate situation, how are you displaying the CKEditor window in Silverlight?  Are you using windowless mode and positioning it so that it looks like it's part of the Silverlight app?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.
my `<a href="http://www.somelink.com">Click here</a>` element was opening a page that took a while to load, and if the child window is closed before it is fully loaded, then my parent crashed. I changed the element as `<a href="http://www.somelink.com" onabort="resizeFunction()">Click here</a>` and it did the job for me. Hope it helps.